# what is the difference between this and address(this) in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

From the solidity document, I get to know that `this` is address of contract. Then why following contract throws errors,
pragma solidity ^0.6.2;

```
contract Sample {
    function getContractAddress() public view returns (address) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

But typecasting `this` as `address(this)`. Then what is the data type of `this`
If I want keccak256, Should I use `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(this, num)) // uint256 num` OR `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(address(this)), num)`
So that I can get the result of `web3.utills.sha3(contractAddress, num) //contractAddress - address(this)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Prior to version 0.5.0, Solidity allowed address members to be accessed by a contract instance, for example `this.balance`. This is now forbidden and an explicit conversion to address must be done: `address(this).balance`.*

Source: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.0/units-and-global-variables.html

So unless you're using deprecated version of Solidity (0.4.x and older), you need to use the conversion to `address(this)`

```
keccak256(abi.encodePacked(address(this)), num)
```